# How can I read width of view inside a Array of View without using GeometryReader?

Tags: swiftui

This is my Array of some Rec I need to know if I can read size of this Rec without using GeometryReader, for example width of Rec?

```
var body: some View {
    
let arrayOfRec = [Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100), Rectangle().frame(width: 200, height: 200)]
    
    VStack
    {
        ForEach(0..<arrayOfRec.count) { index in
            arrayOfRec[index]
        }
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not seem possible to get the width and height of the Rectangle without geometry reader in pure SwiftUI. I tried the methods that were attached to that Shape, but nothing resulted in the size.

Unknown what the use case is, but it is possible to make a custom object that holds the width and height of the rectangle.

```
struct Rectangle_TEST {
    var rectangle: Rectangle
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat
    init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.rectangle = Rectangle()
    }
    func getView(color: Color) -> some View {
        return self.rectangle
            .fill(color)
            .frame(width: self.width, height: self.height)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let arrayOfRec: [Rectangle_TEST] = [Rectangle_TEST(width: 100, height: 100), Rectangle_TEST(width: 200, height: 200)]
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<arrayOfRec.count) { index in
                Text("Width: \(arrayOfRec[index].width), Height: \(arrayOfRec[index].height)")
                arrayOfRec[index].getView(color: .red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above I made the custom object and stores the width and height that can be accessed individually, and then a function that will return a view, and you can pass in whatever modifiers are needed. But, currently, I don't think it is possible to get the dimensions without geometry reader in SwiftUI.